# Inverse image of the canonical projection

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ a ring, $I$ one of its ideal and π the canonical projection. Let $A$ a subring of $R$ not  containing $I$. I need to prove that

$\pi^{-1}(\pi(A)) = A + I$

where π is a ring homomorphism between from $R \to R/I$,

I already proved that when $A$ is a subring (ideal) of $R$ then $\pi(A)$ is a subring (ideal) of $R/I$ and that

$\pi(A) = (A+I)/I$

by replacing the last into the original equation we must have

$\pi^{-1}((A+I)/I) = A + I$

but if A is mapped to $(A+I)/I$ by $\pi$, I don't understand how the preimage can possibly be the set  $A + I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $\phi : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $$\phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B) = A+\phi^{-1}(B)$$ for any subring $A$ of $R$ and any subring $B$ of $S$. Indeed, since $A \subseteq \phi^{-1}(\phi(A)) \subseteq \phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B)$ and $\phi^{-1}(B) \subseteq \phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B)$, it follows that $A+\phi^{-1}(B) \subseteq \phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B)$. On the other hand, if $r \in \phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B)$ then $\phi(r) = \phi(a)+b$ for some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, and so $r-a \in \phi^{-1}(B)$, meaning that $r = a+(r-a) \in A+\phi^{-1}(B)$.

In particular, if you take $B = \{0\}$, then $\phi^{-1}(\phi(A)) = A+\ker \phi$.

Comment: where does $\phi^{-1}(\phi(A)+B) = A+\phi^{-1}(B)$ come from?, my textbook did not introduce it. The proposition I want to prove comes as part of the "First theorem of ring isomorphism". Here https://gioretikto.github.io/mat/algebra/fund_theorem_homomorphism.html I've summed up all the theorems studied so far. This is Theorem 6.4.6 #1. I'll be grateful you can provide a proof with the tools I've at this point. Thanks

Comment: Well, the proof its already provided: just take $\phi = \pi$ and note that $\ker \pi = I$.